# Using angular form in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using `require: '^form'` in my simple directive.

Then I trying to use this form in an ng-show but it doesn't seem to work.

> Note: I don't want to pass the form name in as an attribute.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong? I only want the message to show when the form is invalid.

```
angular.module('xxx').directive('errorWall', errorWall);

function errorWall() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {},
        link: (scope, elm, attrs, frm) => {
            scope.formCtrl = frm;
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="formCtrl.$invalid">You have error messages.</div>'
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you put a break point in the link function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've placed the directive inside the form with at least one input with a ng-model directive on it.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" required />
  <error-wall></error-wall> 
</form>
```

Here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3gv8nvL3/3/ with one form required input.

Comment: Thanks, i had it in a form but It now seems the validation framework i was using was interfering with the result. Appreciate your help